# Store and iterate over sorted file hdfs/spark

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

Task:

I have quite big input files (let's assume 50GB each) on hdfs. I need to sort them, store somewhere(driver program/hdfs/something else?) and then iterate over them until specific condition met.

Questions:

How can I implement it the most effectively?

Where should I save sorted files? If in hdfs how can I stream them to spark, will they be loaded by blocks?

Answer (score 0):

As your file is in HDFS so read it from there only and sort it using below code. I am not sure what type of sorting you want but this code will sort your whole data based on values present in your code

**val data = sc.textFile("hdfs://user/AppMetaDataPayload.csv").map(line=> line.split(","))**

//Use this If you want to store it on memory after sorting and start processing from there only. It will run faster as storing in memory for further processing

**val d1=data.flatMap(_.sorted)
 d1.cache();**

//Use this If you want to save your file in HDFS path
**data.flatMap(_.sorted).saveAsTextFile("hdfs://user/result6.csv")**

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I am interested more in reading file from hdfs. How can I read only part of hdfs file? Let's say 1mb from 50gb file splited accross the cluster.